# Reduce the height of angular material 16 form-field component

Tags: angular, angular-material

In previous versions of angular material I could reduce the height by reducing the font-size and by reducing some specific margins and paddings inside the form-field.

The issue is that the version 16 does not change its height/size with the font-size

[link to form-field](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#form-field-error)

I have tried to use the old methods from various answers here but none seem to work

Comment: Please add code snippets (html, styling etc) of your current form-field component

Comment: I am currently working in a new app and I am using the default angular material html with no changes 
Should I still share something here?

Comment: Indeed, show us what you've tried so far :)

Comment: The "material way" is to change the default density from 0 to -1/-2 etc. It's possible to set via scss but it's a huge pain. See https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#customizing-density. v17 Angular promises better DX for this with design tokens

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Andrew Allen's suggestion

I used this in the theme.scss file that has my custom theme and it worked

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.form-field-density(-3);
```